# Weird Error When My Discord Mod Tried Banning Someone with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so I just joined Stack Overflow but I have a problem with my discord.js bot.
My Moderator Tried Banning Someone with my bot and A error came up in my console. And he didn't get banned. `` (node:5420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions     at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\i7pc\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:5420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:5420) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. ``

Edit: My Code Is

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "Damn, some people are idiots",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.ban();
            message.channel.send("User has been banned by Fish Bot");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`Fish Bot coudn't ban that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve].

Comment: From your provided errors log I can guess that your bot don't have permission do perform ban action.

Comment: There are multiple reasons to get `Missing Permissions` . Check out the [guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#missing-permissions) to see what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the first line from the end it says `Missing Permissions` which means that your discord bot does not have the permission to ban/kick anyone.

Comment: It does have the perms. I've checked the perms.

Comment: can you add try catch into your exec and get full errors details log here

Comment: @FishExploits did you read the comment that I sent? Did you check the link?

Comment: @Radnerus yea. didn't help out :\

Comment: The error doesn't lie, your client is missing some permission or change in it's role heirarchy